# Website loading speed hanpered due to 3rd party scripts in header/footer.

Tags: javascript, loading, pagespeed

So we have a lot of 3rd party solutions integrated with our website. To name a few, google tracking, intercom, onesignal, mouseflow, typekit and a few others. As this list is increasing every month ( we are planning to add MUUT), website loading speed has really become a primary problem. How can I manage these scripts and still not lose on speed?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy solution - you can delay the loading of those scripts.

For example, there's nothing bad if Intercom and Mouseflow would load 5 seconds after the web page was already loaded. You can achieve that by wrapping the JS code that includes Intercom and other scripts into the setTimeout javascript function, e.g.

```
<script>
   setTimeout(
     function(){ put_your_intercom_code_here_instead_this_func() }, 
     3000); // this is the time of the delay in MS, 3000 = 3seconds
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the setTimeout thing but I would start by simply adding a defer attribute to script tags and see how that changes your scores.

Answer (score -2):

My first thinking about is using 3 techniques:

1. Use always minified version of JS libraries. This reduce size of the files
2. Bundle JS files. This allow reduce requests to the server.
3. Set the loading of this resources just before closing body tag `</body>`